# Matlab unique rows cell array / table considering different permutations as equal

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Given a cell array (or table) with, say, two columns, how to find unique permutations of values in the rows? That is, given `A = {'a','b';'b','a';'c','d'}`, what should be returned is `{'a','b';'c','d'}`.

Comment: To remove any confusion about "unique permutations", it might be useful to change the question a bit because actually I think 'ab' and 'ba' are both unique permutations so they should both be returned, no?

Comment: Now I see it's in the title of your question, copy it into your question itself.

Comment: @Tina There is an example given in the body of the question of input and output, so that should be clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `A` is a cell array complicates things. You can do it this way:

```
[~, ~, u] = unique(A);        % get unique labels of cells
u = reshape(u,size(A));       % reshape into original shape
u = sort(u,2);                % sort each row
[~, r] = unique(u, 'rows');   % indices of unique rows
result = A(r,:);              % use those indices into input cell array
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: Would it be easier if it was a table, not a cell array? How would a solution differ then?

Comment: I'm not sure about tables, but I doubt it would be easier. It would definitely be easier if `A` was a char array (char matrix): `A = ['a' 'b'; 'b' 'a';'c' 'd']; [~, r] = unique(sort(A,2), 'rows'); result = A(r,:)`